# Visual Basic Datagrid View change row colour

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

Every other change to the datagrid view works fine but for some reason the row color just wont change.

Ive debugged and my application goes through the loop to change the row color.
Also I have a button that gives the datagrid view a new list and colors the rows accordingly, when I click the button the row colors changes do work!

```
    Public Sub New(measuredValues As List(Of MeasuredValuesModel), valueType As ValueType)
    IsFiltered = False
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    MeasuredValuesList = measuredValues
    uxGrid.DataSource = MeasuredValuesList
    uxGrid.Columns("StepID").Visible = False
    uxGrid.Font = New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

    For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In uxGrid.Columns
        Dim Column As DataGridViewColumn = c
        c.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
    Next

    If valueType = StepItem.ValueType.CalculatedValues Then
        uxButtonFilter.Visible = False
        uxGrid.Columns("DISPOSITION").Visible = False
    End If

    For Each gridRow As DataGridViewRow In uxGrid.Rows
        If gridRow.Cells("PASSFAIL").Value.ToString() = "FAIL" And (gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "Y" Or gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "N/A") Then
            gridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf gridRow.Cells("PASSFAIL").Value.ToString() = "FAIL" And (gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "N" Or gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "N/A") Then
            gridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
        End If
    Next
    uxStepID.Text = MeasuredValuesList.FirstOrDefault.StepID
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    'TODO binding
End Sub
```

Here is the button that works for changing row color.
Maybe it works because it's pressed after the grid has been created? Im not too sure.

```
 Private Sub uxButtonFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles uxButtonFilter.Click
    If IsFiltered = True Then
        uxGrid.DataSource = MeasuredValuesList

        For Each gridRow As DataGridViewRow In uxGrid.Rows
            If gridRow.Cells("PASSFAIL").Value.ToString() = "FAIL" And (gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "Y" Or gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "N/A") Then
                gridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            ElseIf gridRow.Cells("PASSFAIL").Value.ToString() = "FAIL" And (gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "N" Or gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "N/A") Then
                gridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
            End If
        Next
```

Its the exact same loop but it seems to work fine when i use the button.

Comment: Have you checked that your program flow enters through the `If..ElseIf` fulfilling the conditions? Try with  `gridRow.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor`

Comment: Yeh I debugged it and it 100% goes in there.

Comment: And it is not changing the back color when you're debugging?

Comment: No its really weird, I've included the code for the button click that changes the row color with no problems.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the way the If condition are expressed. The first If condition is true not depending on `gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value` because it is in OR with `gridRow.Cells("DISPOSITION").Value.ToString() = "N/A"`. It is sufficent that this one is True to step inside first branch

Comment: If your button is working fine and it's changing the colors the problem is not located at the `If` logic. Try to move your code to your Form `Load( )` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your datagridview isn't loaded fully when you try to recolor the rows?

Since you are setting the datasource, you should put your code that affects the grid after you can make sure that it is finished loading. The column widths change because it is not dependent on the data in the grid, but your colouring is.

Catch the uxGrid.databindingComplete event and try colouring the rows in there